# How to deserialize geojson polygon from npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, geojson

I get the following exception when trying to get entity form npgsql with ef core 3.1

```
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Polygon'
```

My entity:

```
    public class VoteEntity : IVoteEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public Polygon Coordinates { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the exception means is - you need a parameterless constructor in your entity.

Therefor your entity should be:

```
public class VoteEntity : IVoteEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public Polygon Coordinates { get; set; }
    
    //constructor
    public VoteEntity ()
    {
      //you might want to initialise your properties here
    }
}
```